# KDE Neon shutdown issue

Tags: shutdown, kde-neon

A while back I had an issue with kde-neon where the laptop wouldn't power off. The shutdown procedure was fine, with F2 pressed there wasn't any issue but at the end the screen went black but the fan was still working and also a light was indicating that the laptop was still on. Because of that I switched to kubuntu and everything is working fine. But I want to switch back to kde-neon again and I testet the current stable, testing and unstable live images all still with the initial issue, I had to force power off.

Does anyone have/had the same issue? Any recommendations on how to solve it?

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which CPU do you use (AMD or Intel) ? And have you tried upgrading the kernel ? I use kernel 5.3.0-46 in KDE Neon dev-edition and I haven't that problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! i use an amd ryzen cpu. I also believe that it could be a kernel issue. i think the kernel on the live images is the 5.3.0-53. i think i wil try the 5.4.0-33 as used in 20.04 LTS or the 5.7. i am familiar with installing the kernel but not updating it. is there a way to do this automatically or do i have to update it manually from time to time?

Comment: I got trouble after upgrading to 5.3.0-53 (automatically via "pkcon update") so I deleted it and now I use 5.3.0-46 . You can install it via " sudo apt install linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic"

Comment: Also the newest kernel in KDE Neon is currently 5.3 . If you want a newer version you have to compile and install it yourself.

Comment: ok. Thank you! i thought i had to install it from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/. will try the 5.3.0-46.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the kernel as recommended by Parsa Mousavi. I originally planned to switch to 5.3.0-46 but decided for the 5.7.1 at short notice. Everything now works as it should. Thank you Parsa Mousavi for your support!